# Percona Mongodb- Socket exception

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, percona

Getting below `socket exception` while trying to connect to mongodb sharding environment.

> "ctx":"js","msg":"Asio socket.set_option failed with
> std::system_error","attr":{"note":"connect (sync) TCP fast
> open","option":{"level":6,"name":30,"data":"01 00 00
> 00"},"error":{"what":"set_option: Protocol not
> available","message":"Protocol not
> available","category":"asio.system","value":92}}}

```
Error: couldn't connect to server mdb-app-psmdb-db-mongos.percona-mongodb-operator.svc.cluster.local:27017, connection attempt failed: SocketException: invalid status response :
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:372:17
@(connect):2:6
exception: connect failed
exiting with code 1
```

**MongoDB process**

Below is the details of the mongoDB process

```
SLsl 04:47   5:38 mongod --bind_ip_all --auth --dbpath=/data/db --port=27017 --replSet=rs0 --storageEngine=wiredTiger --relaxPermChecks --clusterAuthMode=x509 --shardsvr --enableEncryption --encryptionKeyFile=/etc/mongodb-encryption/encryption-key --wiredTigerCacheSizeGB=0.25 --wiredTigerIndexPrefixCompression=true --config=/etc/mongodb-config/mongod.conf --tlsMode requireTLS --tlsCertificateKeyFile /tmp/tls.pem --tlsAllowInvalidCertificates --tlsClusterFile /tmp/tls-internal.pem --tlsCAFile /etc/mongodb-ssl/ca.crt --tlsClusterCAFile /etc/mongodb-ssl-internal/ca.crt
```

Connection String
Connection works when ssl is false else failing with above exception

> mongodb://backup:backup123456@mdb-app-psmdb-db-mongos.percona-mongodb-operator.svc.cluster.local:27017/?tls=true&authSource=admin&tlsCAFile=/etc/mongodb-ssl/ca.crt&tlsCertificateKeyFile=/tmp/tls.pem&tlsClusterFile=/tmp/tls-internal.pem